# Carrierwave no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am trying to write a method that uses the EXIFR gem to retrieve data (in this case camera model) about photos as they are uploaded using Carrierwave. The current method I am using looks like this in my model:

```
before_save  :get_exif_data 

        def get_exif_data
          imgfile = EXIFR::JPEG.new(photo.filename)

          return

          self.model = imgfile.model  

        end
```

However, I get an error "No such file or directory - IMG_0953.JPG" (or another filename).

My goal is to extract the "type of camera" data using the EXIFR gem's .model method before saving. From the EXIFR gem documentation:

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').model               # => "Canon PowerShot G3"
```

The error suggests to me that my photo.filename has not yet been created. How might I process the image before it is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, something like the following ended up working for me:

```
before_save :get_camera

private
    def get_camera
        self.model = EXIFR::JPEG.new(photo.file.path).model
    end
end
```

Comment: I believe the "correct" way is to use "current_path".  You want to do this in the CarrierWave uploader.  Check out my module [carrierwave-imagesize](https://github.com/mdchaney/CarrierWave-ImageSize) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Michael. I was wondering if this could be taken care of in the uploader. I'll check out your link.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new(Rails.root.to_s + photo.filename_url)
```

carrierwave return an url look like `/uploads/...`
its a relative path to webapp, but `EXIFR::JPEG` will think it a path of system file

Comment: Bad idea on multiple levels - totally doesn't work if using fog.